# In a textfile, How to express if ( Line 1's answer = Line 2's answer ) then

Tags: delphi, text-files

I just started Delphi.

I'm making a simple login form, and the text file (UserInfo.txt) is set up like this

[image]

I just want Delphi to run through the TextFile to look for the string, then if that string equals `edtUseranme.Text` then it must check if that string is equal to the string on the second line.

If it equals then it can continue to the next Form

[image]

Here is my code:

```
for I := 0 to Eof(tFile) do
begin
  Readln(tFile, sLine);
  Inc(I);
  if ReadLn(tFile) = edtUsername.Text then
    begin
      if edtUsername.Text =  then
        begin
          frmMain.Show;
          frmLogin.Hide;
        end
      else
        begin
          ShowMessage('INPUT INVALID (Try again)');
        end;
    end;
end;
```

At that second `if` statement, I don't know what to put after `=`.

Comment: Neither of your images are necessary, so I'm not going to fix the link. Your sample file can be included as plain text here, in the post itself, and the image you provided of your login form does nothing (except maybe let you show off your design skills) - we don't need to see that screen to understand your question. Images should be used only to explain a problem that can't be described in any other way. You should [edit] to include your sample file content as plain text, where it can be copied and pasted if needed for testing.

Comment: I'v added the code

Comment: Doing it for a school project *first time asking online...

Comment: Why you don't use db ?

Answer (score 4):

Like Ken White suggested, you could redesign your text file and then use a `TStringList` to parse it.  That would certainly make it easier to work with the data.  However, if you want to stick with the code you already have, then you could do something more like this instead:

```
var
  tFile: TextFile;
  //Declare variables for temporally storing read username and password
  sUser, sPass, sDivider: string;
  Valid: Boolean;

...

Valid := False;
//use while loop to read every line till the end of file
while not Eof(tFile) do
begin
  //Read username into sUser variable
  Readln(tFile, sUser);
  //Read password into sPass variable
  Readln(tFile, sPass);
  //Read divider into sDivider variable
  Readln(tFile, sDivider);
  //Use if clause to perform multiconditional logical comparison to see if 
  //read username and password equals to those specified in suitable edit 
  //boxes
  //NOTE: Each separate logical condition must be in its own brackets
  if (sUser = edtUsername.Text) and (sPass = edtPassword.Text) then
  begin
    //If conditions are met we set local variable Valid to true
    Valid := True;
    //and then break the loop
    Break;
  end;
end;

//If local variable valid was set to True show the main form
if Valid then
begin
  frmMain.Show;
  frmLogin.Hide;
end else
//else we show message about invalid input entered
  ShowMessage('INPUT INVALID (Try again)');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file format is poorly designed for what you're wanting to do, I'm afraid.

You'd be better off using a more standard format (realizing, of course, that it's totally insecure to store names and passwords as plain text). Delphi makes it easy to work with name/value pairs using TStringList with text like this:

```
Name=Value
```

This would mean your text file would contain the username=password type lines:

```
Bob=Password
Sue=Bambi
```

You then use TStringList to load the file and read the value associated with the name, like this:

```
var
  SL: TStringList;
  UserName, Password: string;
begin
  UserName := Edit1.Text;       // Your username control
  Password := Edit2.Text;
  // You should check to make sure that both the username and password
  // were entered here before proceeding. I'll leave that to you to do.

  SL := TStringList.Create;
  try
    SL.LoadFromFile('C:\Temp\UserInfo.txt');  // Replace with your filename

    // The next line looks for a name in the stringlist equal to the
    // entered username, and if it's found compares its value to the
    // password that was provided.
    //
    // You'll need to handle making sure that you do a case-sensitive
    // (or non-sensitive, depending on your needs) comparison is done
    // if needed.
    if SL.Values[UserName] = Password then 
      // Login succeeded
    else
      // Login failed.
  finally
    SL.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This is obviously just an exercise, not actual production code. There is no need to change the file format just to use a `TStringList`. For instance, you could use `index := SL.IndexOf()` to find the username, and then `SL.Strings[index+1]` to read the password.

Comment: @Remy: Sure you could, until your app blows up because there is nothing at `SL.Strings[index+1]` (except you never need `SL.Strings`, of course). And clearly it's not *actual production code* - it uses a plain text file to store username/password pairs. :-) While you don't *have* to change the format, it's simply silly to jump through lots of hoops instead of simply changing to an easier-to-use format.

Comment: @KenWhite You could prevented the blowing up `if SL.Count > index then Password := SL.Strings[index+1] else ...`

Comment: @Remy: Sure. More unnecessary code to do something that can be done more easily by using built-in functionality. And using the old TextFile I/O functions are just not good, IMO, when there are much better ways. (Just FTR, there was zero code when I started writing my answer, so I was unaware the poster was already using readln.)